# Suppress unused fill levels in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data where when I create a bar plot, I always want certain levels to have a specific color. An example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble(var = paste("Group", 1:9),
              val = runif(9),
              grp = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 9, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp))
```

[image]

In this example, let’s say that I always want `A` to be `red`, `B` to be `blue`, `C` to be `orange`, and `D` to be `black`. I can manually specify this using `scale_fill_manual()`.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange",
                               "D" = "black"))
```

[image]

However, if not all values are present, they still show up in the data.

```r
dat %>%
  filter(var != "Group 7") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange",
                               "D" = "black"))
```

[image]

Even though this is no `grp = "C"` in the data, that value still shows in the legend. I have tried to add `drop = TRUE` to drop unused levels, but that doesn’t seem to work.

```r
dat %>%
  filter(var != "Group 7") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange",
                               "D" = "black"),
                    drop = TRUE)
```

[image]

Is there any way to automatically drop unused levels? I know I could change the vector of values to exclude unused levels, but for this project, it’s not always clear which levels will be present, and because this same palette will be used over and over, it would be nice to only have to specify the palette once.

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. After dropping `"Group 7"` there is no `'C'` label in legend for me.

Answer (score 2):

Is your version of ggplot up to date? On version 3.3.3, I am unable to replicate your issue. The example you provided drops level "C" from the legend as you wanted:

```
dat %>%
  filter(var != "Group 7") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange",
                               "D" = "black"))
```

[image]

We can, however, control which levels appear in the legend with the breaks argument:

```
dat %>%
  filter(var != "Group 7") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange", "D" = "black"), 
    breaks = c('A', 'B')
  )
```

[image]

You can specify which legend items to include programmatically if you first save your filtered data set separately, then reference in the plotting commands:

```
df.filtered <- dat %>%
  filter(var != "Group 7")

df.filtered %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "C" = "orange", "D" = "black"), 
    breaks = sort(unique(df.filtered$grp))
  )
```

Comment: Interesting. I was on version 3.3.4. I reverted back to 3.3.3 and got the expected behavior. With 3.3.4 and the development version from GitHub, I see the unexpected output. It appears that a bug was introduced in 3.3.4. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4545